# individual t-test vs tukeyHSD comparison

Tags: anova, t-test, p-value

We observed that in a particular scenario, the p-values for t-test and tukey were exactly opposite and we are trying to figure out what the problem is

Here is the output from ***Tukey***. Observe the p adj value for **1Hr-0Hr** is **1.00**

```
$sampleIL1.b
                diff         lwr        upr     p adj
1Hr-0Hr 4.625395e-05 -0.02575430 0.02584681 1.0000000
2Hr-0Hr 7.331162e-04 -0.02506744 0.02653367 0.9999993
3Hr-0Hr 9.294719e-03 -0.01650584 0.03509527 0.8883340
4Hr-0Hr 9.738356e-02  0.07158300 0.12318411 0.0000000
5Hr-0Hr 8.832659e-01  0.85746534 0.90906645 0.0000000
2Hr-1Hr 6.868622e-04 -0.02511369 0.02648742 0.9999995
3Hr-1Hr 9.248465e-03 -0.01655209 0.03504902 0.8903946
4Hr-1Hr 9.733730e-02  0.07153675 0.12313786 0.0000000
5Hr-1Hr 8.832196e-01  0.85741909 0.90902020 0.0000000
3Hr-2Hr 8.561602e-03 -0.01723895 0.03436216 0.9183866
4Hr-2Hr 9.665044e-02  0.07084989 0.12245100 0.0000000
5Hr-2Hr 8.825328e-01  0.85673222 0.90833334 0.0000000
4Hr-3Hr 8.808884e-02  0.06228828 0.11388940 0.0000000
5Hr-3Hr 8.739712e-01  0.84817062 0.89977173 0.0000000
5Hr-4Hr 7.858823e-01  0.76008178 0.81168289 0.0000000
```

Here is the output from t-test for **0Hr to 1Hr**. p val **2.2e-16**

```
> t.test(subset(dfIL1.b, sampleIL1.b == "0Hr")$expIL1.b,subset(dfIL1.b, sampleIL1.b == "1Hr")$expIL1.b, var.equal = T)

        Two Sample t-test

data:  subset(dfIL1.b, sampleIL1.b == "0Hr")$expIL1.b and subset(dfIL1.b, sampleIL1.b == "1Hr")$expIL1.b
t = -44.314, df = 14, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -4.849263e-05 -4.401526e-05
sample estimates:
   mean of x    mean of y 
3.684513e-06 4.993846e-05
```

Also we ran pairwise.t.test with pool.sd=TRUE

```
> pairwise.t.test(dfIL1.b$expIL1.b, dfIL1.b$sampleIL1.b, p.adjust.method="none", paired=FALSE, pool.sd=TRUE)

        Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

data:  dfIL1.b$expIL1.b and dfIL1.b$sampleIL1.b 

    0Hr     1Hr     2Hr     3Hr     4Hr    
1Hr 1.00    -       -       -       -      
2Hr 0.93    0.94    -       -       -      
3Hr 0.29    0.29    0.33    -       -      
4Hr 2.8e-14 2.9e-14 3.6e-14 6.3e-13 -      
5Hr < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16

P value adjustment method: none
```

And pairwise.t.test with pool.sd=FALSE

```
> pairwise.t.test(dfIL1.b$expIL1.b, dfIL1.b$sampleIL1.b, p.adjust.method="none", paired=FALSE, pool.sd=FALSE)

        Pairwise comparisons using t tests with non-pooled SD 

data:  dfIL1.b$expIL1.b and dfIL1.b$sampleIL1.b 

    0Hr     1Hr     2Hr     3Hr     4Hr    
1Hr 6.4e-10 -       -       -       -      
2Hr 1.7e-08 2.6e-08 -       -       -      
3Hr 5.1e-09 5.2e-09 7.2e-09 -       -      
4Hr 3.6e-11 3.6e-11 3.7e-11 2.0e-11 -      
5Hr 1.0e-10 1.0e-10 1.0e-10 1.1e-10 1.7e-10

P value adjustment method: none
```

We understand that when we use pool.sd=TRUE it is calculating the SD over all the population.
There is no such switch in the TukeyHSD.

What is the correct p-value? Do we expect the p-value from individual t-test match that of tukey? If not how can we explain the totally contradictory outputs.

---

Below is the R script for this

```
#IL1-b
expIL1.b <- c(0.857425947276836,0.903963346900899,0.893778808720919,0.881383937743047,0.923319316602323,0.945970781909345,0.834916492855318,0.825398007760462,0.0996023807305112,0.0966480155313406,0.0933980600669783,0.0997956014647892,0.103582006542215,0.099982475528176,0.0940411398284604,0.0920482642207111,0.00983390768244454,0.00890198805673889,0.0089606738691259,0.0109314909331226,0.00880735371563553,0.00908997220124592,0.0093985103556747,0.0084633284402903,0.000836129701064413,0.000657216786787257,0.000623314673432558,0.000810975721156488,0.000706834822394536,0.000769078681139018,0.000763341619034504,0.000727513557998224,5.29952004766082E-05,4.87157675921214E-05,4.66252905713546E-05,5.31362526508671E-05,5.06518382891046E-05,5.18050169824326E-05,4.50166703130002E-05,5.05616364298123E-05,3.342561539243E-06,3.43997806842929E-06,3.58387255667504E-06,3.75440670699944E-06,3.63469341601403E-06,3.85897946985264E-06,4.025017618571E-06,3.83659566611408E-06)
sampleIL1.b <- c("5Hr","5Hr","5Hr","5Hr","5Hr","5Hr","5Hr","5Hr","4Hr","4Hr","4Hr","4Hr","4Hr","4Hr","4Hr","4Hr","3Hr","3Hr","3Hr","3Hr","3Hr","3Hr","3Hr","3Hr","2Hr","2Hr","2Hr","2Hr","2Hr","2Hr","2Hr","2Hr","1Hr","1Hr","1Hr","1Hr","1Hr","1Hr","1Hr","1Hr","0Hr","0Hr","0Hr","0Hr","0Hr","0Hr","0Hr","0Hr")
dfIL1.b <- data.frame(expIL1.b, sampleIL1.b)

a.aov <- aov(expIL1.b ~ sampleIL1.b, dfIL1.b)

TukeyHSD(a.aov)


t.test(subset(dfIL1.b, sampleIL1.b == "0Hr")$expIL1.b,subset(dfIL1.b, sampleIL1.b == "1Hr")$expIL1.b, var.equal = TRUE)
t.test(subset(dfIL1.b, sampleIL1.b == "0Hr")$expIL1.b,subset(dfIL1.b, sampleIL1.b == "1Hr")$expIL1.b, var.equal = FALSE)

pairwise.t.test(dfIL1.b$expIL1.b, dfIL1.b$sampleIL1.b, p.adjust.method="none", paired=FALSE, pool.sd=TRUE)
pairwise.t.test(dfIL1.b$expIL1.b, dfIL1.b$sampleIL1.b, p.adjust.method="none", paired=FALSE, pool.sd=FALSE)
```

Comment: How many hypotheses are you testing?  An adjusted p-value will always be larger than an individual test because you are adjusting for multiple comparison.  The key issues are the number of t tests and the magnitude of the adjustment. It is entirely possible that you can reject the individual hypothesis or hypotheses and not be able to reject after adjustment.  But it is also possible that the djustment will not be large enough to change rejection to non rejection.

Comment: it is 15 comparisons.

Comment: But tell us more about your data because you could be misapplying the methods and your code may need checking.

Comment: With 15 comparisons you can expect a large difference.

Comment: Thank you. That is what we expected. I posted the data in the question as R script at the very end.

Comment: If all the individual p-values for the t tests were approximately 2 e-16 a Bonferroni  adjustment which is very conservative would  3 e-15.  So something else is going on. Are you using different data sets for each t test involving 15 observations each?